# Next.JS 13 Loading UI - Production Ready?

Tags: typescript, next.js, netlify, vercel

Is the loading UI functionality of Next 13 ready for production? I cannot seem to get it too work on Vercel and Netlify. I have not read anything official saying that this will not work on either. I have it working locally with `next dev`. I am able to see the loading UI as my CSS and other assets load on to the page. However when I use Netlify's and Vercel's build pipeline with Github Actions to setup and run the site neither of them show the loading UI as CSS and the other assets load onto the page. I am able to see the text on the page for a brief second while the CSS loads without any styling.

To Note: I am using doing this with TypeScript

Summary:

Locally running `next dev` works as expected.

Running on Vercel or Netlify with `next build` doesn't work.

I understand Next 13 is in beta and not all features will work, just looking for some confirmation or a work around.

Next Version: `^13.1.6`

Next Config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: No it's not ready for productio yet because the `appDir` is still in beta stage. I can confirm that the issue still exists.